# AngularJS select option initialize

Tags: angularjs, select

I have this select tag:

```
<select class="form-control" data-ng-model="contact.title" data-ng-options="title.title as title.title for title in titles track by title.title">
    <option></option>
</select>
```

and when I will edit the title nothing is selected but **contact.title** is **Mag.**. Therefore **Mag.** should be selected. Does anyone know what I have to do in order that Mag. is selected?

[image: titles]

Comment: Try `data-ng-options="title.title as title for title in titles track by title.title`

Comment: Try removing 'track by' portion. Just a thought.

Comment: what do you mean by "when I edit the title"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I found tinkering around in a jsfiddle, the 'track by' was unnecessary.
Please try removing it.

```
<select class="form-control" data-ng-model="contact.title" 
    data-ng-options="title.title as title.title for title in titles">
<option></option>
</select>
```

Changing the 'track by' portion to $index or another value changes the selection. It's best to not use it if you are sure all *titles* will be unique.

Answer (score 0):

Working code for me:

```
<select class="form-control" data-ng-model="contact" data-ng-options="title.title for title in titles track by title.title">
  <option></option>
</select>
```

In controller:

```
$scope.titles = [{title: "abc"}, {title: "pqr"}, {title: "xyz"}];
$scope.contact = $scope.titles[0];
```

Try this.

Comment: My problem is that if I change the title the whole contact is destroyed because ng-model of title is set to contact.

Comment: Can you add jsfiddle or plunker link here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$scope.titles = [{title: "abc"}, {title: "pqr"}, {title: "xyz"}];
$scope.contact = {};
```

And:

```
<select name="repeatSelect" id="repeatSelect" ng-model="contact.title">
      <option ng-repeat="title in titles" value="{{title.title}}">{{title.title}}  </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ng-init` directive to have a default option in a select. You can use something like:

html:

```
<select ng-init="contact.title = titles[0]"
        ng-model="contact.title"
        ng-options="title.title for title in titles">
</select>
```

js:

```
$scope.titles = [{title: "Title A"}, {title: "Title B"}, {title: "Title C"}];
```

Comment: Try to use it like this way

Comment: See the note about "This directive can be abused to add unnecessary amounts of logic into your templates..." on the angular documentation for [ngInit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)

Answer (score 0):

### tl;dr

Set the initial value the model for *contact* in the controller, change the *ng-model* attribute of the select list to just *contact* and update the *ng-options* to `data-ng-options="title as title.title for title in titles"`.

#### Selecting "Mag."

> Does anyone know what I have to do in order that Mag. is selected?

In order to select *Mag.* (the first item in the list of titles, ensure that there is a property *contact* setup in the controller to the first element in the array of titles (i.e. `$scope.contact = $scope.titles[0];`). Also, change the *ng-model* attribute of the select from **contact.title** to **contact**.

#### ngOptions expression syntax

Also, review the syntax for *comprehension_expression* under the **Arguments** section of [ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions).
The *titles* data sources is an array, so under *array data sources*, we have an expression like this format:

> select **as** label **for** value **in** array

The value of *select* should not be the same as *label*. So update the **ng-options** attribute like this:

```
data-ng-options="title as title.title for title in titles track by title.title"
```

And as has already been mentioned, the **track by** clause is unnecessary. It would be useful if there was a different property we needed to account for (e.g. an integer named *id*). Thus the **ng-options** attribute can be simplified to:

```
data-ng-options="title as title.title for title in titles"
```

#### Example

See it demonstrated in the snippet below:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.titles = [{
      title: "Mag."
    }, {
      title: "Mag.(FH)"
    }, {
      title: "Mag. Dr."
    }, {
      title: "Dr."
    }];
    $scope.contact = $scope.titles[0];
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <select class="form-control" data-ng-model="contact" data-ng-options="title as title.title for title in titles">
  </select>
  <div>Contact.title: <span ng-bind="contact.title"></span></div>
</div>
```

#### Avoid *ngInit*

It has been suggested that ng-init be used to set the initial value, however, there is a note about this on the documentation for [ngInit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit):

> This directive can be abused to add unnecessary amounts of logic into your templates. There are only a few appropriate uses of *ngInit*, such as for aliasing special properties of *ngRepeat*, as seen in the demo below; and for injecting data via server side scripting. Besides these few cases, you should use [controllers](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller) rather than *ngInit* to initialize values on a scope.<sup>[1](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)</sup>

This is because (one of) the uses of controllers is to:

> Set up the initial state of the `$scope` object.<sup>[2](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller)</sup>

Business logic like that should not be added the template.